# Why does this pointer to C++ function code generate a compile error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can anyone solve this? I can’t seem to find the solution anywhere, but I see no logical reason why the line below (with the comment showing the compile error) should be a problem.

**Note**: This question is a derivative of [How can a C++ base class determine at runtime if a method has been overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801949/how-can-a-c-base-class-determine-at-runtime-if-a-method-has-been-overridden)

```
class MyClass
{
        typedef void (MyClass::*MethodPtr)();  


        virtual void Method()
        {
                MethodPtr a = &MyClass::Method; // legal
                MethodPtr b = &Method;  // error C2276: ‘&’ : illegal operation on bound member function expression

                if (a == b)     // this method has not been overridden?
                        throw “Not overridden”;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function. This takes care of name mangling. So what you are trying to do will not work in a standards compliant C++ compiler.

Comment: If you could do this, C++ would have something like [closures][1].

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29