# can't initialize map of method pointers in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, visual-studio-2012

I have a function like the following:

```
//Parser.cpp
//...
Parser::Parser(CommandFactory & fact, 
               ArrayList<std::string> & expression)
{

    operations["*"] = &fact.createMultiplyCommand; //error C2276
    operations["/"] = &fact.createAdditionCommand; //error C2276
    operations["+"] = &fact.createAdditionCommand; //error C2276
    operations["%"] = &fact.createModulusCommand; //error C2276
    operations["-"] = &fact.createSubtractionCommand; //error C2276

    infixToPostfix(fact,expression);

}
//...

//Parser.h
//...

    Parser (CommandFactory & fact,
            ArrayList<std::string> & expression);

    Stack<Command*> tempCommandStack;
    ArrayList<Command*> postfix;

    /// Destructor.
    ~Parser (void);

private:
    //syntax is: <return_type> (*)()
    //syntax for a class method is: <return_type> (<class_name> *)();
    //syntax with a typedef is: typedef <return_type> (<class_name> * <typedef_name>)();
    //                          typedef <return_type> (*<typedef_name>)()


    std::map<std::string, Command * (*)()> operations; 
    std::map<std::string,int> precedence;
//...
```

It also may help to know that `CommandFactory` is an abstract class (what is passed in is concrete)

The error I receive is C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong exactly when I define the mapping. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
//CommandFactory.h
#ifndef _COMMANDFACTORY_H_
#define _COMMANDFACTORY_H_

#include "Subtract.h"
#include "Add.h"
#include "Divide.h"
#include "Multiply.h"
#include "Modulus.h"
#include "Negation.h"
class CommandFactory
{
public:

    virtual Subtract * createSubtractionCommand() = 0;
    virtual Add * createAdditionCommand() = 0;
    virtual Divide * createDivisionCommand() = 0;
    virtual Multiply * createMultiplyCommand() = 0;
    virtual Modulus * createModulusCommand() = 0;
    virtual Negation * createNegationCommand() = 0;
    ~CommandFactory(void);

};

#endif   

//StackCommandFactory.h

#ifndef _STACKCOMMANDFACTORY_H_
#define _STACKCOMMANDFACTORY_H_

#include "Add.h"
#include "Subtract.h"
#include "Divide.h"
#include "Multiply.h"
#include "Modulus.h"
#include "CommandFactory.h"


class StackCommandFactory : public CommandFactory
{
public:



    virtual Subtract * createSubtractionCommand(void);
    virtual Add * createAdditionCommand(void);
    virtual Divide * createDivisionCommand(void);
    virtual Multiply * createMultiplyCommand(void);
    virtual Modulus * createModulusCommand(void);
    virtual Negation * createNegationCommand(void);

protected:
    Subtract * sub;
    Add * add;
    Divide * div;
    Multiply * mul;
    Modulus * mod;
    Negation * neg;

};

#endif   // !defined _STACKCOMMANDFACTORY_H_

//StackCommandFactory.cpp
#include "StackCommandFactory.h"

Subtract * StackCommandFactory::createSubtractionCommand(void)
{
    return sub;
}

Add * StackCommandFactory::createAdditionCommand(void)
{
    return add;
}

Divide * StackCommandFactory::createDivisionCommand(void)
{
    return div;
}

Multiply * StackCommandFactory::createMultiplyCommand(void)
{
    return mul;
}

Modulus * StackCommandFactory::createModulusCommand(void)
{
    return mod;
}

Negation * StackCommandFactory::createNegationCommand(void)
{
    return neg;
}
```

Comment: can we see what CommandFactory is?

Comment: What version of what compiler on what platform are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows with Visual Studio 2012, not sure what the compiler name is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code. Mostly centring about the use of member functions rather than global functions. You try to get the member functions from an object, where you should be getting them from the class itself. ( i.e. instead of `&fact.createAdditionCommand` you need `&CommandFactory::createAdditionCommand`.) But this results in an unbound member function, which means you need to call it using `(fact.*fn)()` - i.e. with an object of the CommandFactory class. This is not ideal - and not what you're looking for. You are looking for a bound member function. Using these in non C++-11 applications is possible, but ugly. 
You can use `boost` libraries to really help with that (and the code below will pretty much work unchanged other than some `std` to `boost` style changes.) If you're using C++-11 then you can use the C++-11 function objects.

Here's a complete example derived from your source:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct Command {};
struct Subtract : Command {};
struct Add : Command {};

class CommandFactory
{
  public:

    virtual Subtract * createSubtractionCommand() = 0;
    virtual Add * createAdditionCommand() = 0;
};

class StackCommandFactory : public CommandFactory
{
  public:

    virtual Subtract * createSubtractionCommand(void);
    virtual Add * createAdditionCommand(void);

    Subtract * sub;
    Add * add;
};

Subtract * StackCommandFactory::createSubtractionCommand(void) { return sub; }
Add * StackCommandFactory::createAdditionCommand(void) { return add; }

class Parser
{
  public:
    Parser (CommandFactory & fact);

    std::map<std::string, std::function<Command*()> > operations; 
};

Parser::Parser(CommandFactory & fact)
{
  operations["+"] = std::bind(&CommandFactory::createAdditionCommand, &fact);
  operations["-"] = std::bind(&CommandFactory::createSubtractionCommand, &fact);
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  Add add;
  Subtract sub;

  StackCommandFactory command_factory;
  command_factory.add = &add;
  command_factory.sub= &sub;
  Parser parser(command_factory);

  std::cout<<"&add = "<<&add<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Add = " <<  parser.operations["+"]() <<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"&sub = "<<&sub<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Sub = " <<  parser.operations["-"]() <<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I get the output

```
&add = 0x7fff58d538d8
Add = 0x7fff58d538d8
&sub = 0x7fff58d538d0
Sub = 0x7fff58d538d0
```

Showing that the Add object returned by going through the parser is the same as that stored into the CommandFactory. (And same for the Subtract object)

Comment: Before C++11 I'd use `boost::function` instead. If thats not an option, you can build something similar using functor objects instead to wrap the bound member functions.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the code that you've written. probably because I'm not sure what you mean by bounded and unbounded functions. Are there any stackoverflow posts/articles you recommend I read about this?

Comment: Here's the details on std::bind, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind and a nice SO answer about boost::bind and boost::function is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527413/how-boostfunction-and-boostbind-work#527983

Comment: Hey I'm trying to use functor objects to bound the member functions as you said (since I can't use boost or c++11) but am having some issues. I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733390/cant-initialize-functor-objects-when-passing-derived-class-in-c/15735616?noredirect=1#15735616. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in standard C++. For reasons have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802059/why-does-this-pointer-to-c-function-code-generate-a-compile-error) & [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/850cstw1.aspx).

**EDIT:**
Instead of storing "Command * (*)()" into operations, why not change "operations" value type to store "Command *" ? Or perhaps have a relook into the low-level design?

Answer (score -1):

sorry try

operations["*"] = fact.createMultiplyCommand;

or

operations["*"] = fact->createMultiplyCommand;

Comment: that gives me more errors. It then says that the function is missing the list of arguments (error C3867)

Comment: ok im looking at

Command * (CommandFactory::*)()

does fact.createMultiplyCommand return a Command ptr? some of the implementation detail is missing,

operations["*"] = &(fact.createMultiplyCommand());

normally i use boost::bind to do this type of thing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304203/how-to-use-boost-bind-with-a-member-function an example of how easy it is with boost bind ...

Comment: unfortunately this is a class project so I can't use `boost`. However yes, `fact.createMultiplyCommand()` returns a `Command` pointer. When I change that statement from `std::map<std::string, Command * (CommandFactory::*)()> operations;` to `std::map<std::string, Command * (*)()> operations;` it removes some errors later down the error list.

Comment: can you provide the definition for fact.createMultiplyCommand

Comment: I've provided the implementations. The mapping must be from `fact` because `fact` is a specific implementation of CommandFactory. CommandFactory is just an interface, it has no implementation of the methods. I also changed the implementation a little: `std::map<std::string, Command * (CommandFactory::*)()> operations;` to `std::map<std::string, Command * (*)()> operations;` because the former caused more errors.