# can't initialize functor objects when passing derived class in C++

Tags: c++, functor

This question stems from a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513453/cant-initialize-map-of-method-pointers-in-c). I cannot use any external libraries or the C++ 11 spec. Meaning I can't use std::bind, std::function, boost::bind,boost::function etc. I have to write it myself. The issue is the following:

Consider the code:

**EDIT**

Here is a complete program that exhibits the problem as requested:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>


class Command {    
public:
    virtual void executeCommand() = 0;
};

class Functor {
public:
    virtual Command * operator()()=0; 
};

template <class T> class Function : public Functor {
private:
    Command * (T::*fptr); 
    T* obj;                  
public:
    Function(T* obj, Command * (T::*fptr)()):obj(obj),
        fptr(fptr) {}

    virtual Command * operator()(){
        (*obj.*fptr)();   
    }            
};

class Addition:public Command {
public:
    virtual void executeCommand(){
        int x;
        int y;
        x + y;
    }
};

class CommandFactory {
public:
    virtual Addition * createAdditionCommand() = 0;
};

class StackCommandFactory: public CommandFactory {
private:
    Addition * add;
public:
    StackCommandFactory():add(new Addition()) {}

    virtual Addition * createAdditionCommand(){
         return add;
    }
};

void Foo(CommandFactory & fact) {
    Function<CommandFactory> bar(&fact,&CommandFactory::createAdditionCommand);
}

int main() {
    StackCommandFactory fact;
    Foo(fact);
    return 0;
}
```

The error it gives is `"no instance of constructor "Function<T>::Function [with T=CommandFactory] matches the argument list, argument types are: (CommandFactory *, Addition * (CommandFactory::*)())`

I think it's complaining because I'm passing it a derived type. I have to use pointers/references to the abstract classes because `fact` may not be a StackCommandFactory later down the road.

I can't say:

```
void Foo(CommandFactory & fact){
      Function<CommandFactory> spf(&fact,&fact.createAdditionCommand); //error C2276

}
```

because of then I receive error C2276 which says (as in the question I linked to) `'&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression.`

So explicitly my question is: "How do I initialize this functor object so that I can use it with the above mentioned interfaces?"

Comment: Can you make a small **complete** program that exhibits this problem?  Debugging un-seeable code is *far* more difficult than reducing the code to something we can all see.

Comment: Your `Function` template class should be header only, as `Foo()` is the only place where there is enough information to instantiate the template.  This is the reason for the linker error.

Comment: Identifiers which begin with an underscore and are followed by an uppercase letter are reserved, i.e., `_FUNCTOR_H_` should be `FUNCTOR_H_` (or just `FUNCTOR_H`).  Actually, in the global namespace, any identifier beginning with an underscore is reserved.

Comment: @DrewDormann I made a small complete program as requested that exhibits the problem. quamrana I haven't had a linking error yet but will keep this in mind later thanks! Ed I didn't know that, I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: What is `Add` in the error? I see the class `Addition` but not `Add` anywhere else in your code ...

Comment: That was a typo. I just corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modification of my original answer that seems to do what you need, without using the any functor stuff from C++11 or boost.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Command {};
struct Subtract : Command {};
struct Add : Command {};

class CommandFactory
{
  public:

    virtual Subtract * createSubtractionCommand() = 0;
    virtual Add * createAdditionCommand() = 0;
};

class StackCommandFactory : public CommandFactory
{
  public:

    virtual Subtract * createSubtractionCommand(void);
    virtual Add * createAdditionCommand(void);

    Subtract * sub;
    Add * add;
};

Subtract * StackCommandFactory::createSubtractionCommand(void) { return sub; }
Add * StackCommandFactory::createAdditionCommand(void) { return add; }

class CommandGetterImpl
{
  public:
    virtual CommandGetterImpl* clone() const=0;
    virtual Command* get()=0;
    virtual ~CommandGetterImpl() {};
};

class CommandGetter
{
  public:
  Command* get() { return impl_->get(); }
  ~CommandGetter() { delete impl_; }
  CommandGetter( const CommandGetter & other ) : impl_(other.impl_?other.impl_->clone():NULL) {}
  CommandGetter& operator=( const CommandGetter & other ) {
     if (&other!=this) impl_= other.impl_?other.impl_->clone():NULL;
     return *this;
  }
  CommandGetter() : impl_(NULL) {}
  CommandGetter( CommandGetterImpl * impl ) : impl_(impl) {}
  CommandGetterImpl * impl_;
};

class Parser
{
  public:
    Parser (CommandFactory & fact);

    std::map<std::string, CommandGetter > operations; 
};

template<typename MEMFN, typename OBJ >
class MemFnCommandGetterImpl : public CommandGetterImpl
{
  public:
  MemFnCommandGetterImpl(MEMFN memfn, OBJ *obj) : memfn_(memfn), obj_(obj) {}
  MemFnCommandGetterImpl* clone() const { return new MemFnCommandGetterImpl( memfn_, obj_) ; }
  Command* get() { return (obj_->*memfn_)(); }
  MEMFN memfn_;
  OBJ * obj_;
};


template< typename MEMFN, typename OBJ >
CommandGetter my_bind( MEMFN memfn, OBJ * obj )
{
  return CommandGetter( new MemFnCommandGetterImpl<MEMFN,OBJ>(memfn,obj) );
};

Parser::Parser(CommandFactory & fact)
{
  operations["+"] = my_bind(&CommandFactory::createAdditionCommand, &fact);
  operations["-"] = my_bind(&CommandFactory::createSubtractionCommand, &fact);
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  Add add;
  Subtract sub;

  StackCommandFactory command_factory;
  command_factory.add = &add;
  command_factory.sub= &sub;
  Parser parser(command_factory);

  std::cout<<"&add = "<<&add<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Add = " <<  parser.operations["+"].get() <<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"&sub = "<<&sub<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Sub = " <<  parser.operations["-"].get() <<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well it took me three days and a conversation with my professor to fully understand why what I was doing wasn't working and to understand what you wrote above. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need an explicit cast on the 2nd parameter of the bar instance:

```
Function<CommandFactory> bar(&fact,
  reinterpretet_cast<Command *(CommandFactory::*)()>(&CommandFactory::createAdditionCommand));
```

Besides, you're missing parens for the method pointer attribute in `Function`:

```
Command * (T::*fptr)();
```

This error might have prevented you to find the solution above.

You are also missing the `return` keyword in the `operator()` there (a mistake that I often do because of my functional programming habits):

```
virtual Command * operator()(){
   return  (obj->*fptr)();
}
```

---

You can avoid the cast by making the return type a template parameter:

```
template <class T, typename D> 
class Function : public Functor {
private:
    D * (T::*fptr); 
    T* obj;
public:
    Function(T* obj, D * (T::*fptr)()): obj(obj),  fptr(fptr){}
    virtual Command * operator()(){
        return (obj->*fptr)();
    }            
};

void Foo(CommandFactory & fact){
    Function<CommandFactory, Addition> bar(&fact, &CommandFactory::createAdditionCommand);
}
```

Note that I did not templatize `Functor` after all. While it seemed a good idea at first to me, it make things a bit more complex. If you wish to make `Functor` a template too, the return type will have to be exactly the same, you cannot use an inheritance relation between them, unless you make them both parameters of the `Function` template. As a rule of thumb, whenever you stumble on a template issue like that, remember that template are like C macros at the core, it's a rewriting mechanism, which will expand the template into real C++ types (functions or classes) separately. You can picture the problem that way:

```
template <typename T, typename D>
class Function : public Functor<D> { /* ... */ };
```

will be expanded to

```
class Function<CommandFactory, Addition> : public Functor<Addition> {
    /* ... */
};
```

`Functor<Addition>`  and `Functor<Command>` bears no relationship at all; these are two different classes.

If C++ template did carry the notion of bounded polymorphism (like in Java or C#), it could have perhaps been possible to write it in way close to your intent.

I recommend:

- keeping the `Functor` a simple class, to make the code simpler to work with for the time being, and
- if the need arises later on, trying to refactor a working version with that new feature.

Comment: I tried with my own experiment, which wasn't exactly as yours actually. You prompted me to verify it, and I saw my mistake. I hope this time my assessment of the problem is correct.

Comment: Currently it works in the test program so now I'm trying to figure out why it's throwing a `- pure virtual function call` exception. It's like it's not finding the right method. It calls the right one in the test program though

Comment: The only issue with using multiple types in the template is that when I try to use a map of Functor objects, I get the same casting issue `Function<CommandFactory,Addition> bar(&fact,&CommandFactory::createAdditionCommand);
 std::map<std::string,Functor<Command> *> the_map;
 the_map["+"] = &Function<CommandFactory,Addition> (&fact,&CommandFactory::createAdditionCommand);`

Answer (score -3):

Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to use member function pointers as opposed to `std::function`. More generally,

```
typedef std::function<void()> Command;
typedef std::function<Command()> Functor;
```

Really, there's absolutely no need whatsoever for any member function pointers in your code.

Comment: I guess the reason for down-votes is that he mentioned that "I cannot use any external libraries or the C++ 11 spec. Meaning I can't use std::bind, std::function, boost::bind,boost::function etc. I have to write it myself."